# Excel VBA: Copying and Pasting Data via CommandButton for all worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new to VBA and need some help with implementing a tool:

Essentially, I want to create a CommandButton that automatically copies range D9:L18 and pastes it to Q9:Y18 for my active worksheet. Furthermore, once I press the button, I want this process to be repeated for all other worksheets (around 40) with the exception of two specific ones.

Can you please give me a hand with this?

Your help is much appreciated - many thanks indeed.

Edit:

There is an error @ `Sheet.Range("D12:L18").Select` for some reason - perhaps you can help me? Thanks.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim Sheet As Worksheet

    For Each Sheet In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If Sheet.Name <> "Definitions" And Sheet.Name <> "fx" And Sheet.Name <> "Needs" Then

            Sheet.Range("D12:L18").Select
            Selection.Copy
            Sheet.Range("Q12:Y18").Select
                Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Suggest you try three things: 1) Record a macro copying your range. 2) Record a macro selecting all the tabs you require then pasting the data. 3) Look at this code and work out the best way of combining the two. If you get stuck come back with the code and ask for help.

Comment: ^^ Ditto  One of the best ways to learn is have the record function create initial code, and then adjust it.  It is not perfect, but will get you started.

Comment: Don't use the `select`. Just use `Sheet.Range("...").Copy` and `Sheet.Range("...").PasteSpecial...`

Comment: Tested here and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recording a macro to copy and paste the cells you want is the best way to get the code to copy a single sheet.

But to do the work in all your sheets, use this:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click() 
    Dim Sheet As Worksheet 
    For Each Sheet In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets 
        If Sheet.Name <> "Definitions" And Sheet.Name <> "fx" And Sheet.Name <> "Needs" Then 
            Sheet.Range("D12:L18").Copy 
            Sheet.Range("Q12:Y18").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False 
        End If 
    Next 
End Sub
```

---

To add the button, go to the `developer` tab in excel, add an `ActiveX` button.
Design mode will be turned on. Double click that button, the code to be run when it's clicked will be shown in VBA editor. Put your copy code there inside the `Private Sub YourButtonName_Click()` method.

To make the button work, turn off the design mode. (That's done in the developer tab in excel window)

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works great. One thing though: I want all my sheets to be subjected to the macro, with the exception of two sheets that must not be altered - how would I express this? Many thanks for your help :)

Comment: That is the `If` inside that `For Each` statement. Where you read `SheetYouDontWantToCopy1` and `SheetYouDontWantToCopy2`, change that for these two sheets names. If the Sheet the code is trying to copy now has a name equal to one of your two sheets, the if will jump that sheet.

Comment: Thanks, appreciate it. It doesn't quite work yet though. [code]Do you mind having a look please? Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim Sheet As Worksheet

    For Each Sheet In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If Sheet.Name <> "Definitions" And Sheet.Name <> "fx" And Sheet.Name <> "Needs" Then
            
            Range("D12:L18").Select
            Selection.Copy
            Range("Q12:Y18").Select
            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
                
        End If
    Next
End Sub[/code]

Comment: When you use `Range`, you are taking the Range from a specific sheet, the one where the code is inserted. But if you use `Sheet.Range....`, you are taking the range from the sheet you want. So, you should substitute both `Range("D12:L18").Select` and `Range("Q12:Y18").Select` with `Sheet.Range("D12:L18").Select` and `Sheet.Range("Q12:Y18").Select`.

Comment: Thanks Daniel - tried this. I get a run time error (1004) saying "Select method of Range class failed". I will insert the code in my original post to make it clearer where I could have gone wrong. Cheers

Comment: Ok, that's probably because that sheet is not active. In fact, you don't need to select and use selection.copy. You just use Range.Copy. See I edited the answer with that.